# capturing this outside of class scope possible?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

To relieve the strain of lambda definitions crowding in my class, I've decided to move the lambda definitions outside the class. There is a problem however, as capturing `this` is very convenient. This is what I have in mind:

```
struct S;

constexpr auto get_lambda(S* const s) noexcept {
  return [s] {
    // blah, blah, but I need to dereference s
  }
}
```

Does there exist a workaround for the inconvenience? EDIT: The inconvenience being the additional typing, as well as not having access to private/protected members of `S`.

Comment: What exactly is the inconvenience? That you have to say `s->member` instead of `member`? Or something else?

Comment: Perhaps you are saying that you need access to private members of `S`?

Comment: @noobProgrammer Yes, yes, exactly so

Comment: @MikeSeymour I edited.

Comment: Have you tried making `get_lambda` a friend of `S`? I'm not sure if it will work, just an idea.

Comment: @Tyler The friend idea works under clang, but not gcc, look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59766

Comment: For the UB olympics, we have this answer: `template<class S> struct self:S { constexpr auto get_lambda() const { return [=]{ blah blah }; }; static constexpr auto get_lambda( S const* s ) { return static_cast<self const*>(s)->get_lambda(); }; };`, used as `self<S>::get_lambda(s)`.  Almost certainly works, but completely UB.  Does not give access to `private` members, barring `friend`ing.